# For, enter to focus next element disables js validation

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

Please check below js fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lfz567tw/

I have created a form in which when I enter, it selects next input and at last, submits the form.

But this function disables my validation function and on submitting the form, function validate() is not working.

Is there any way I can fire function `validate()` also when submitting the form?

Comment: Your function is already being called. Check my test edit for your jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/Lfz567tw/20/
you should check it only on one place either on form tag or on submit button. It is not required to check that on both places.

Comment: Thank you so much @nikhil , you are rite. It is actually calling the function , its just that my ids are different.

Comment: That was really a silly mistake...

Answer (score 0):

### There is simple example to show you how you can check or call your validate function before form submittion

[**e.preventDefault**](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)  : Used for prevent default functionallity

```js
$(function() {
$("#entertonext").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
// validate code (calling function)
validate();
});
});

function validate() {

alert('Validating');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-block"  id="entertonext">
   <form  name="bank" action="#" method="post">
      <div class="form-group row"  >
         <label for="default-input" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Account No.</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control entertonext" name="acc_no" id="acc_no" placeholder="Account No."  tabindex="1" onblur="validate(this,event)">
            <span id="msg8"></span>     
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <label for="default-input-rounded" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Branch Name</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group icon icon-lg icon-color-primary">
               <input type="text" class="form-control entertonext" name="b_name" id="b_name" placeholder="Branch Name"  tabindex="2">                                 
            </div>
            <span id="msg2"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" id="drawn" >
         <label for="default-input" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">IFSC Code</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control entertonext" name="ifsc_code" id="ifsc_code" placeholder="IFSC Code"  tabindex="3">
            <span id="msg5"></span>  
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" id="deposited">
         <label for="default-input" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Address</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control entertonext" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address"  tabindex="4"></textarea>
            <span id="msg6"></span>   
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row" id="deposited">
         <label for="default-input" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Bank Balance</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control entertonext" name="balance" id="balance" placeholder="Bank Balance"  tabindex="5">
            <span id="msg6"></span>   
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-sm-10">    
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary entertonext"  tabindex="6">Submit</button>  
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```